# Suppres a field when printing crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

Would it be possible to suppress a filed when printing CR. Basically I have a report with a field that I would like to have displayed when viewing trough Infoview (DHTML viewer) and have it suppressed when printing the report.
Crystal Reports XI R2 Enterprise.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this to the Head Section of the HTML output?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

if so, you can control what prints, and what doesn't with print.css.